# Independence of linear combinations of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

This seems like a straightforward question, but I'm having trouble finding anything on it.

Suppose we have a set of random variables, $X = (X_1,...,X_p)$ (the components of which may not be independent), and another random variable $Y$. If $X \perp Y$ (jointly independent), then is it true that $a^T X \perp Y$, for some vector of constants $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since independence states that the joint probabilty of any sets $\{X \in A\}\;$ and $\{Y \in B\}\;$ equals the product of both probabilities.

Comment: Is your questions answered or do you need a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Thanks for you response and for checking in. I'm not sure I understand the answer. I understand that for $X \perp Y$, $P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)$, but what does this tell me about $P(X_1 + X_2 \in C, Y \in B)$ (which is what I'm after with the linear combination idea, where here $p=2$)?

Comment: No problem. $X \perp Y \Rightarrow \forall A_1, ..., A_p, B\colon$ 

$$P(X_1 \in A_1, ..., X_p \in A_p, Y \in B) = P(X_1 \in A_1, ..., X_p \in A_p)P(Y \in B)$$

which especially holds for all $C$ in your example, since $\{X_1 + X_2 \in C\} \Rightarrow \{X_1 \in \tilde{A}_1, X_2 \in \tilde{A}_2\}$ for appropriate sets $\tilde{A}_1, \tilde{A}_2.$

Comment: Right - thanks very much!